# Perform t-test R two datasets and multiple variables

Tags: r, t-test

I have two data sets (two different countries), and for each data set I have 3 variables: 2 independents (years and car model), 1 dependent (sales)

To make it more visual it would look something like this:

Country 1

```
Car_Model  Year    Sales
A          1       100
A          2       200
B          1       80
B          2       90
C          1       66  
C          2       20
```

Then for the second data set:

Country 2

```
Car_Model  Year       Sales
A          1          120
A          2          220
B          1          82
B          2          92
C          1          62
C          2          22
```

I have been asked to perform a t-test to check if there is a significant difference between countries, but taking into consideration the variable car_model and year. However, I can not understand if it is possible to perform a  t-test in such a problem, and which kind of t-test should I perform or how I should use the variables.

I think the idea here is to check the significant difference of model A in country 1 against model A in country 2, then model B in country 1 against model B in country 2, and so on. And at the end get a p value based on those previous p values. Is it possible to do this using a t-test in R?